# Magento and exif photo automatic rotation. How to prevent or fix?

Tags: catalog, image, magento-1.9, simple-product, upload

i'm on Magento CE 1.9 and i have some problems with image uploading. I discovered that the problem is with the exif. That tag isnt work good. On my shared server i cant install php plugins etc.. do you know some kind of plugin or code to fix that? I can fix it with php only but i cant figure out how to integrate it into Magento. Really i think it's may be an really common problem. So if you help me you will help others... if you can, Thanks.

Comment: No one faced this ? D: ..so i'm alone :sad:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a module to remove the exif tags from the photos you want to upload. An easier way is to remove them before uploading the photos to magento with any free software.

Comment: Could you pls explain briefly?